# Validate form with Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate my form, but I had this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

I included the js files validation jquery-validate.min.js and jquery-validate.js.Thanks

index.html

```
<form id="form1">
<label for="phone">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ok" />
</form>
```

file.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){    
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name"

    }
})

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#form1").valid();
});

});
```

Comment: first of all you have to include only one file the min one or the source one, not both

Comment: Check your `Network` tab in development tools to confirm the validation plugin is loading.

Comment: Yup, it looks as though it's not loaded.

Comment: @RobertMoskal do you have another solution because I didn't understand where's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this and note how the scripts are included:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){    
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please specify your name"
        }
    });
    
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
```

```css
#form1 label.error {
    color: #FB3A3A;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
<label for="name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ok" />
</form>
```